# Extraction of field labels in Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

Do you know how we can extract the field labels of all fields by code C# or SQL?

[image]

I can extract the "display name" but not the labels.

My purpose is to extract the list of labels for each field in the different forms.

Comment: You can export the translations.. this way you can edit in bulk & reimport. What's your purpose?

Comment: My purpose is to extract the list of labels for each field in the different forms

Comment: Did you find any alternative?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, CRM form fields & whole funda are stored in xml. You can try to [query](http://sriharirad.blogspot.com/2014/02/retrieve-crm-form-metadata-xml.html?m=1) & see the Form Metadata.

I recommend exporting translations & see through all the labels in one place. Alter the label text, correct the typos, spelling mistakes at one shot & reimport.

You said what you want but not why you want it (purpose). Please check 'Form related tools' in xrmtoolbox to see if it's helpful.